# how to get modified count in mongod using findAndModify

Tags: mongodb

As we know mongodb returns `modifiedCount` when using `update(updateOne,updateMany)` even `updateOne` which might returns 0 or 1, so the question when using `findAndModify`, how to get the `modifiedCount` returned? I know `findAndModify` returns old or new record which might or might not change, sometimes when we use operator like `$min`, `$max`, `$inc`, it might modify zero or one record, I got requirement that I want to assert the `modifiedCount`, anybody knows how to deal with this, thanks in advance.